# Android Studio Linear Layout Design issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am having an issue with designing  Android Studio Layout for App. In linear layout, I want to add first two layouts in the first column horizontally and then in the next column, I wish to add that three buttons in horizontally and finally in the last column want to add Listview. Any help would be highly appreciated. As currently, everything falls into one row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >


         <james.view.VideoView
               android:id="@+id/remoteVideoView"
              android:layout_width="120dp"
             android:layout_height="90dp"
              />

        <james.view.VideoView
               android:id="@+id/localVideoView"
              android:layout_width="120dp"
              android:layout_height="90dp"
             />

             <Button
             android:id="@+id/startVideoButton"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Start Call"
              />

             <Button
              android:id="@+id/stopVideoButton"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="End Call"
             />

             <Button
             android:id="@+id/sendmessage"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="msg"
             />


             <ListView
             android:id="@+id/errorList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayou
```

This is how I want my layout to be

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't understand Constraints. You can use regular LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        >

        <james.view.VideoView
            android:id="@+id/remoteVideoView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <james.view.VideoView
            android:id="@+id/localVideoView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startVideoButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Start Call"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stopVideoButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="End Call"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendmessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="msg"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/errorList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Quite simple!**

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

This is exactly how you want, Just copy paste and your job is done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <james.view.VideoView
            android:id="@+id/remoteVideoView"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/localVideoView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <james.view.VideoView
            android:id="@+id/localVideoView"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/remoteVideoView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startVideoButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Start Call" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stopVideoButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="End Call" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendmessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="msg" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/errorList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3">

    </ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Try it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample xml, similar to your image. Since your code uses constraintLayout I have created the xml using constraintLayout instead of linear layout. I have created this from the design screen and not from the text screen. This is the xml `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="67dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="67dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="193dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="193dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`
Please see if this helps you. This is not exact screen as per your requirements.